# How to connect to oracle from client computer while server and client both are in different domain in the same network?

Tags: oracle, dns

I am using oracle 10g enterprise edition. My server has windows server 2003 OS and client has windows 7 professional. Server is in domain "A" and client is in domain "B". I can access the server from client through windows. I can connect to the database in server from the local administrator account of client. But when login into the client from the domain user (Admin group user) and try to connect to the database it gives error. I can connect to the server from client through windows even by the domain user account. The error has no code. It says "There may be some problem in the connection or the server may not be ready for the connection".

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Showing *how* you connect to the database might help. Which Oracle client software, or application if that is what generates that message, and the driver it's using; what connection string you're using; what kind of authentication you're using; etc. Are there any logs which give a more helpful error message?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. i do not have the log file right now because the systems are in a different place. This error comes when i create a service from net manager. suppose i created a service "TestService". I filled all the fields like port, IP Address of server( another time i gave the name of the server with full domain name) and global database name and all the other things.. After filling all the fields while the testing of service is done it shows the above error without error code.